# Upload a file to a folder outside wwwroot at a different server in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to upload files to a folder that is located outside the hosting server of an ASP.NET Core project. I tried different ways but none worked so far. I also tried to use fttp upload but the server provider does not allow that. Here is my code

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> DevicePhotoGalary(int id, IFormFile file) // IFormFile for one Photo and IFormCollection for Multi Photo
        {
            var QuestionObj = await _questionRepo.GetQuestionById(id);
            if (QuestionObj == null)
                return NotFound();

            var uploadFolderPath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "IQ Questions"); //location must be changed here

            if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFolderPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolderPath);

            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
          

            var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolderPath, fileName);
            // var filePath = uploadFolderPath + fileName;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                file.CopyTo(stream);
            }

            QuestionObj.Image =  fileName;
            await _questionRepo.UpdateQuestion(QuestionObj);

            return Ok(); 
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I use "AppContext.BaseDirectory".  On my server it's the parent of wwwroot.  (Inetpub)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use FTP in your server. The easiest way is to deploy a simple web program on the server that needs to upload files, and the program contains an upload interface.

Then you can call the interface in the `DevicePhotoGalary` method.

**Code like below**

---

```
public IActionResult DevicePhotoGalary( IFormFile file) 
{
    var uploadFolderPath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "IQ Questions"); //location must be changed here

    if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFolderPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolderPath);

    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);


    var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolderPath, fileName);
    // var filePath = uploadFolderPath + fileName;
    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        // Invoke api in the server which will save the content
        //file.CopyTo(stream);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: it is a good idea. let me try it out and update you. thanks